# DataType.Currency unobtrusive validation not working

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

This code is not working, can anybody can help me?

Model:

```
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(HeelpResources), Name = "AdViewModel_Price_Label")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMsgRequiredField", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(HeelpResources))]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMsgPriceFormat", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(HeelpResources))]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Generates this in the client-side:

```
data-val-number="The field Preço: must be a number".
```

and not the message that is supose to be in Resource "ErrorMsgPriceFormat".

Thanks.

Comment: How are you entering the data into the `input` field?

Comment: Hi, here in Portugal the currency as the format 2.000,00 and I want to accept the format 2000,00 - For now I had the regular expression: RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\,\d{1,2})?$")

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure what you're going to have to do is something more along these lines:

```
public string FormattedPrice { get; set; }
```

decorate that with the RegEx you provided to ensure they enter a valid currency value and bind the `input` to that field.

Then when you get into your action you're going to want to do something like this with [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx):

```
decimal result;
var success = decimal.TryParse(o.FormattedPrice, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture, out result);
```

where `o` is the instance of the model that was posted to the action. Further, the `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint` should translate to `,` just like it does in your example because of your culture. I know that's a little backwards, but think about it like this, in the US the decimal separator is `.` so for your culture that same enumeration value translates to `,`.

If it's successful in parsing it then `success` will be true and you can set `result` to `o.Price`.